# Java3D JOGL (Win7 64) launch causes run-time native code error

Tags: windows, jogl, java-3d

I am upgrading my Java3D Win7 app to use JOGL interface, as Oracle has stopped shipping Java3D support in the 1.8.0_33 JRE.  I am running Win7 SP1
under Parallels Desktop 10 for the Mac on a MacBook Pro.  I am developing with the Eclipse Mars2.0 IDE (Win 64).

The compiler is happy with the build, so it must be finding all the JOGL imports.  It's not complaining about any missing files.  But, when I launch the app, the app window exists for a fraction of a second, then disappears.
This is the error text in the console:

> #
>       # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>       #
>       #  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fef0ea34d9,     pid=5032, tid=1496
>       #
>       # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_77-b03) (build    1.8.0_77-b03)    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.77-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)    # Problematic
>   frame:    # C  [prl_gldd.dll+0x134d9]    #    # Failed to write core
>   dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of
>   Windows

Comment: That exception normally indicates a txt file containing the whole exception, can you copy it here?

Comment: It is a known problem, the culprit is inside Parallels and it has never been fixed for years despite our complains. Sorry but please use VirtualBox instead. The JogAmp community isn't responsible the bugs and the limitations of proprietary virtualization softwares.